# Sanitize query string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a webpage with a query string.

In PHP I have:

```
$querystring=$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
echo "<html><head></head><body>
<a href='index.php?$querystring'>test</a>
</body></html>";
```

**Do I need to sanitize the querystring?**
If yes, how do I sanitize and what are some possible attacks if I don't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `htmlspecialchars($query, ENT_QUOTES)` to prevent any XSS attacks.

```
echo "<html><head></head><body>
<a href='index.php?".htmlspecialchars($querystring, ENT_QUOTES)."'>test</a>
</body></html>"
```

But still, you should white list any parameters, because a smart attacker could forge a query and attempt a [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack.

Answer (score 21):

**Update**: FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated since PHP 8.1, see official PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

---

If you're running PHP >= 5.2.0, use `filter_input` or `filter_input_array`.

Let's say your URL and query string is something like `http://example.com/?liquor=gin&mixer=tonic&garnish=lime`.

To filter, you would do something like the following.

```
/*
 FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING removes most dangerous characters. That may 
 not always be what you want. Read the PHP filters docs. 
 
 We are also overwriting the $_GET array (the query string) with the sanitized
 versions of these variables.
*/

$_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

/* 
rebuild query string using white listed variables, 
not $_GET to prevent variable injection as Mārtiņš Briedis 
suggests above.
*/

$qv['liquor']  = $_GET['liquor'];
$qv['mixer']   = $_GET['mixer'];
$qv['garnish'] = $_GET['garnish'];

# build and URL encode the query string using the above array.
$querystring = http_build_query( $qv );
```

Comment: It might be more "elegant" if you create a function for that and pass an array of allowed keys and iterate through that (also I think it makes it more readable).

Comment: Also, you might want to do something like $_GET['liquor'] ?? '', in case the parameter is not filled.

Comment: FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated since PHP 8.1 https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are accessing the query params as variables in the PHP 5.x as follows but is prone to XSS

### Vulnerable to XSS

```php
<?php
// http://example.com/mypage.php?a=hi&b=wow&c=<script type='text/javascript'>alert('XSS Attacked!');</script>

try{
    $q = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str( $q, $arr );
    extract($arr);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'a is = ' . $a;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'b is = ' . $b;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'c is = ' . $c;
    echo '</pre>';

}
catch(Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}


?>
```

### Prevent XSS from $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

To prevent XSS from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`,

- Use `htmlentities` to read the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and decode the query string using `html_entity_decode`.
- Use `parse_str` to extract array of key values of query parameters.
- Filter and Sanitize the array using `filter_var_array` with array to sanitize as the first arg and `FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED` as the second argument.
- Use `extract` to make keys php variables with respective values.

```php
<?php
// http://example.com/mypage.php?a=hi&b=wow&c=<script type='text/javascript'>alert('XSS Attacked!');</script>
try{
    $q = htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    parse_str( html_entity_decode($q), $arr );
    $arr=filter_var_array($arr, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    extract($arr);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'a is = ' . $a;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'b is = ' .  $b;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo 'c is = ' .  $c;
    echo '</pre>';

}
catch(Exception $e){
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use urlencode function.

htmlspecialchars/htmlentities are more appropriate when you are going to output value of the query param at the link's title for example, but no at the href/src attributes.

Answer (score -3):

You can sanitize the query using several ways, but that is not the place to do that. Even if you send a safe query by GET, someone can change the query on the address bar or using tamper data. You have to sanitize on index.php (or wherever you process the data). If you are using MySQL, you have to sanitize this way:

```
$field = mysql_real_scape($_GET['field']);
```

Comment: Why do people keep recommending mysql_real_escape() for XSS/CSRF injection1!!!?! SQL injection and XSS/CSRF are completely different security concerns.

Comment: +1 to what John Cartwright said. Steve, your suggestion works for preventing SQL injection. But in this case, we want to filter output -- what's added to our HTML -- to prevent XSS attacks.